# Cannot subscript a value of type '[xxx]' with an index of type '(Int, () -> ())'

Tags: swift, indexing, subscript

I have this issue, the error accessing the index of an array. The index should be an integer, but its not working. I have tried initially with a variable, but in this example I have changed it to integer, 0, just to show its no the variable that is the issue.

```
   let location = SNStore.Welland[index].locations[0] {
                    if location.timestamp > 0 {

                    }
                }
```

the error is:

```
 Cannot subscript a value of type '[LocationStore]' with an index of type '(Int, () -> ())'
```

So could someone explain why the array doesn't want an int for its index? Its weird and I don't understand.

I checked for the declaration of locations in the quick help and it correctly shows how locations was declared in the struct. (in the struct it has curly braces on the end to initialise it empty.)

```
var locations: [LocationStore]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscripting in Swift is done behind the scenes by calling a special method `subscript` which takes an `Int`.  So when you write:

```
locations[0]
```

Swift is really calling the `subscript` function with the value inside of `[]`:

```
locations.subscript(0)
```

You can't call `subscript` directly, but it is there and you can define custom subscripting for your own classes by implementing `subscript` for them.

You are confusing Swift with the extra curly braces `{ }` which follow `locations[0]`.  Swift interprets the `{ }` and their contents as a closure with signature `() -> ()` (takes no input, returns no output).  Because of *trailing closure syntax*, Swift then interprets that closure as a second argument to the `subscript` function that is called on `locations` to perform the indexing.  This subscripting function takes one argument, an `Int`, but you are passing two arguments, an `Int` and the `() -> ()` closure.  That is what the error message is telling you.

The fix is to remove the extra `{ }`:

```
let location = SNStore.Welland[index].locations[0]
if location.timestamp > 0 {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Stunning. Brilliant. Something so simple and its stopped me in my tracks for days. I have been totally on the wrong lines trying to solve it. You are a kind soul for taking your time to help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting problem.  That really is a crazy and unexpected error message!

Comment: Indeed, this is a questionable language design. You can't have an IF LET statement that refers to an element of array.

Comment: @Oscar, I think it works as expected with `if-let`.  For example, this works `let arr: [Int?] = [1,2,3];if let x = arr[1] { print(x) }`.  Do you have an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for the reply. I guess I should have said that it doesn't work without the semicolon, but I (and perhaps many) Swift programmers never use semicolons. I don't think I have one in my entire app, and would never have guessed the reason for this seemingly irrelevant error message.

Comment: @Oscar,  the semicolon in my comment has nothing to do with this issue. It just separates the two lines of code in my comment. Really you’d write those on separate lines. This error doesn’t show with `if let` at all. It does give the weird error if you leave off the `if` from the `if let`, but that is an odd thing to do.

Comment: @vacawama Yes, the example is the same as the OP's but with "if" in front of it:

if let location = SNStore.Welland[index].locations[0]
{
    do something
}  It's what this entire post is about, is it not?

Comment: The OP's issue was caused because they followed a `let variable = value[0]` with a closure.  Perhaps they meant it to be an `if let`, but they left off the `if`.  If you put the `if` there, the weird error goes away because Swift then knows that the `{ }` belongs to the `if` statement and doesn't try to interpret it as a second parameter to the `[0]` subscripting operator. I disagree with your statement: *You can't have an IF LET statement that refers to an element of array.* Yes, you can.  That works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have extra parentheses. Try this:

```
 let location = SNStore.Welland[index].locations[0]

 if location.timestamp > 0 { /*do something*/ }
```